# How to deploy nginx-ingress controller to kubernetes master nodes by using "controller.nodeSelector" option?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I need only deploy nginx-ingress controller to kubernetes master nodes, by using Helm chart "ingress-nginx".  It provided an option "controller.nodeSelector" to select k8s nodes for deployment. So I want to use this option to select k8s master nodes with label `node-role.kubernetes.io/master=`, but tried different formats, can't have it work as expected.

Failed case:

```
helm install --set controller.hostNetwork=true --set controller.hostPort.enabled=true --set controller.extraArgs.enable-ssl-passthrough="" --set controller.replicaCount=1 --set controller.nodeSelector."node-role\.kubernetes\.io/master"="" --namespace rwe ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Could you help advise how to have this option take into effect?  Thanks.

Comment: What error you are seeing, in most of the case master node will be tainted with NoSchedule so we can't schedule any pod into master node.

Comment: You are correct, need remove the NoSchedule taint at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove the taint from master node to make it schedulable

```
kubectl taint node master node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Add  a label `master=true` to the master node

```
kubectl label nodes master master=true
```

And then use below helm command. Note `--set-string` instead of `set`

```
helm install --set controller.hostNetwork=true --set controller.hostPort.enabled=true --set controller.extraArgs.enable-ssl-passthrough="" --set controller.replicaCount=1 --set-string controller.nodeSelector.master=true --namespace rwe ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Comment: Or better yet just create a `values.yaml` file, to get out of that `--set` mini-language business; either way, I think Kiruba's observation about the chart [needing a toleration](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml#L164) is the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

For those who use NGINX Ingress Controller packaged by Bitnami, First download its [helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller/#installing-the-charthttps://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller/#installing-the-chart) then open and update `ingress-nginx/values.yaml` file with following content

```
affinity:
 nodeAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
    - matchFields:
      - key: metadata.name
        operator: In
        values:
        - your-k8s-master-node-name
```

Finally install the chart

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx
```